# I need help identifying this "Mystery Bike" (could possibly be a real ferrari?)

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

Good day to everyone,

So i have this really old bike.
[image: a red bike with ferrari sticker]

I don't know its brand and model. The paint is still stock, and it has a Ferrari sticker with the name "Michael Schumacher" and signature. also came with Mavic rim brake rims.

It has the letters "M O B" engraved at the back of the top tube.
[image: MOB Engraving]

Uses a Pilo D201 Dropout Hanger.
[image: Pilo D201 Dropout Hanger]

The frame was built fairly clean. Rear triangle only have mount for V-Brakes only (No u-brake mounts or cantilever cable guides)(also no Rack mounts) could i assume it's a race bike?
[image: The Frame]

Came with a Square taper bottom bracket and a threadless headtube.
[image: Headtube]

Came with an RST Fork(with stock paint).
[image: RST Fork]

Precisely built and uncut steerer tube with a built in thread for top cap.
[image: Steerer tube]

Also have center stand mounts(?).
[image: center stand mounts]

Comment: Welcome to the site - That is a well-documented question, thank you for adding plenty of useful photos.

Comment: In the first photo. the fork legs appear to be a slightly steeper angle than the head tube.  Is that how it really is, or is that a trick of the camera lens ?   If its real, the bike may have had a hard landing or a frontal impact, pushing the fork back into the frame.

Comment: i think it's only a camera trick

Comment: Anything on the bottom of the bottom bracket tube? Usually there is a serial number there

Comment: there is indeed a serial number under there.

Comment: @Anni - care to share the SN?

Answer (score 7):

Few facts:

[Michael Schumacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher) was at the Ferrari F1 team from 1996-2006, so this bike very likely dates from this period. Even if it is a custom-made one.

A quick web [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=giant%20michael%20schumacher%20bike) shows that such MSC collection models existed back in the days, it can't be confirmed that this bike is original but also not totally ruled out since the idea obviously existed.

[image]

Most of these were Giant MTBs but I didn't find any pictures matching the characteristic top tube shape, so I don't think yours is one of these because all of them had simple tube shapes and no *extravaganza*.

Also worth noting that none of this bikes popping up in web searches had Ferrari branding, they are usually pretty strict about their brand usage, that could also indicate it is a custom bike respectively a frame builder's (unofficial) one-off.

Comment: I find the bike yoke to be the most similar thing to a Giant Bike, Though i find the extended top tube, The drop out hanger, and the words letters MOB weird.

Comment: It is hard to find anything meaningful with regards to _mob(sters)_, especially together with Ferrari/Italy terms. ;)

Comment: V brakes instead of cantis, and more shaped tubes might suggest a later model than the one pictured in the answer.  So might the suspension forks, but they might not be original

Comment: I think the frame originally came with the fork, same paint (also stock), and a precisely built steerer tube for the frames headtube.

Comment: Some more motorsports nerdisms: If the yellow Mavic rims should resemble the traditional golden rims Ferrari F1 cars had, the [1998 F310B](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrari_F310B) car was the last one with these, the were silver until after Schumacher left 2007 and cars got generally ugly with wheelcaps and stuff. So, it's sure probably a late 90s bike. :)

Comment: @Anni you've got the bike in front of you and I haven't but I'm not convinced the red is a perfect match between frame and fork in your first photo

Comment: Sorry im a little bit colourblind and small shading difference is hard to see for me and now that you've pointed that out i see it

Answer (score 3):

Coming at your question from the other angle, there is a [Filipino bicycle manufacturer called MOB](https://www.mobphilippines.com/about) for "Men on Bikes." They claim to have been selling since 1998, so there's some overlap with the Schumacher stint at Ferrari. I tried the Wayback Machine on their website to see if I could look at old models, but either there weren't snapshots of the site that long ago or they used to have a different website address.

You could visit MOB's contact form with a link to your question and/or your serial number.

I found some pictures of old MOBs on Facebook. They can't be your bike because they don't have the extended top tube where "MOB" is stamped into the butt of yours.

I'm curious about the down tube, though. Yours looks like it has a continuous cross section of a rounded triangle. It's hard to tell in the photos below, but the bright yellow 2001 mountain bike might have the same tube shape, even though its top tube is clearly a different angle than yours. It would make more sense to have the top tube extension when it's more horizontal, so the fun stamped butt might not have survived an industry-wide change in geometry.

Your frame has also cable stops in a different place and no mount for rear disc calipers, but it could be an early or rare model.

[image: MTB 2001]
[image: Front-sus road bike?]

Comment: Yes that was our first clue as well, as someone in the Philippines, and people who looks at it just say its just MOB ph because of the engraving, but based from the pictures of their bikes from before to now, they never used that kind of yoke, the extended top tube, and the Pilo D201 dropout hanger. I messaged them already and still waiting for a reply. The MOB engravings could mean differently, i mean it could mean its a custom bike and it was the 1st owners initials.